# how to simulate a traffic scenario for cars

Tags: routes, simulation, ibm-connections, city, traffic-simulation

im trying to do a project about routing cars through cities, the idea is to know the amount of cars that are on the streets so the vehicle can be routed through the less congested route.
For that i would need to install a gps on every car of the city so i can know their positions and to know which is streets are less congested.
I just want to simulate a traffic situation where there is a certain amount of cars on the city and make them move around the city so the amount of cars in each street is changing continously (like a real situation) so my application can fetch that information instead of fetching it from real cars.
I found the ibm connected car simulator but i couldnt find a way to fetch the cars position from there.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://sumo-sim.org. It is a fully featured open source traffic simulation. You can either get a static trace of vehicle positions or you can access these values via an API and trigger re-routing in a running simulation.
The documentation is at http://sumo-sim.org/wiki and you can get help at sumo-user@lists.sourceforge.net.